# Migrating Azure SDK 1.6 TableStorage and Writing/Reading Entity handlers

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

Have some legacy code using Azure SDK 1.6 that I have been tasked with updating to latest/2.7.  Below is a quick example of saving an entity.  Note that it appears we use a custom serializer of our own.  I know how to convert to the new CloudTable for basic read/write but I am unsure how to port the serialize/deserialize logic we are using.

```
 internal class FaultyMessageRecord : TableServiceEntity {

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Byte[ ] Content { get; set; }
}

public void StoreMessage( FaultyMessage faultyMessage ) {
        var context = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext( );
        context.WritingEntity += ( o, e ) => entrySerializer.WritingEntity( e );
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        context.AddObject( tableName, new FaultyMessageRecord {
            PartitionKey = "",
            RowKey = now.ToString( "s" ), //sortable datetime
            Content = (byte[])faultyMessage.TransportMessageContent,
            Created = now
        } );
    }
```

Partially ported code:

```
 internal class FaultyMessageRecord : TableEntity {

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Byte[ ] Content { get; set; }
}

public void StoreMessage( FaultyMessage faultyMessage ) {           
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(new FaultyMessageRecord
        {
            PartitionKey = "",
            RowKey = now.ToString("s"), //sortable datetime
            Content = (byte[]) faultyMessage.TransportMessageContent,
            Created = now
        });
        table.Execute(insertOperation);          
    }
```

Reading seems to have a similar logic which i can provide if necessary, but basically it uses the context.ReadingEntity to pass in the deserializer.

Here is a representation of the serializer class:

```
public class UntypedAtomSerializer {


protected string[ ] hardcodedProperties;

  public UntypedAtomSerializer( params string[ ] hardcodedProperties ) {
     this.hardcodedProperties = hardcodedProperties;
  }


  public void WritingEntity( System.Data.Services.Client.ReadingWritingEntityEventArgs e ) {
            var propertyEl = e.Data
                .Elements( ).Where( el => el.Name.LocalName == "content" )
                .Elements( ).Where( el => el.Name.LocalName ==  "properties" )
                .FirstOrDefault( );
            SerializeProperties( e.Entity, propertyEl );
  }

  private void SerializeProperties( object tableEntry, XElement propertyEl ) {
            SerializeProperties( tableEntry, propertyEl, this.hardcodedProperties );
  }


  private static void SerializeProperties( object entry, XElement propertyEl, params string[ ] hardcodedProperties ) {
            var tableEntry = entry as IDictionaryEntity;
            if ( tableEntry != null ) {

                var elNS = XNamespace.Get( BaseAtomSerializer.WCF_DATA_NAMESPACE );
                var attrNS = XNamespace.Get( BaseAtomSerializer.WCF_METADATA_NAMESPACE );
                //add any properties that are part of the BaseStorageEntity dictionary
                foreach ( var kvp in tableEntry.ExtraProperties.Where( kvp => !hardcodedProperties.Contains( kvp.Key ) ) ) {
                    var newEl = new XElement( XName.Get( kvp.Key, elNS.NamespaceName ), kvp.Value );
                    if ( kvp.Value == null )
                        newEl.Add( new XAttribute( XName.Get( "null", attrNS.NamespaceName ), "true" ) );
                    else
                        newEl.Add( new XAttribute( XName.Get( "type", attrNS.NamespaceName ), BaseAtomSerializer.MapCLRtoAtomType( kvp.Value.GetType( ) ) ) );
                    propertyEl.Add( newEl );
                }
            }
  }
}
```

And it's instantiated as `UntypedAtomSerializer entrySerializer = new UntypedAtomSerializer( "PartitionKey", "RowKey", "Timestamp", "Created", "Content" );` for use by the StoreMessage method above.

Comment: Can you share what is happening inside the serializer?

Comment: Sure, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have hard requirement to keep the same functionality and dependency on Atom, you can get to table service context via GetTableServiceContext() method on the CloudTableClient instance. Note that, you'd need to set the format to use Atom (.Format.UseAtom() method). 
Context has the same WritingEntity and ReadingEntity event handlers.

However, these APIs are obsolete. We instead recommend using ITableEntity/TableEntity's ReadEntity and WriteEntity methods. 
If you have 3rd party objects that cannot derive from ITableEntity, you can refer to the following blog post on how to serialize them: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/announcing-storage-client-library-2-1-rtm.aspx

Comment: Well, yes we have existing data in the table that we need to retrieve so have to stick with the same serialization.  Are there any examples of using TableEntity's ReadEntity/WriteEntity that allow for the same effect?